# Riemann vs. Ihara's $\zeta$ Function Variable Question

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

The [Euler product for the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function#Properties) implies that
$$
    \log\zeta_R(z)=\sum_{m>0}\frac{P(mz)}{m} \tag{R},
$$
whereas the [Ihara zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ihara_zeta_function) for a graph $G$--all can be expressed in the same basic form:

$$\log \zeta_I(z)= \sum_{m> 0} \frac{N_mz^m}{m} .\tag{I}$$

What confuses me is the different appearance of the variable $z$. Since $\displaystyle P(mz)=\sum_{p\,\in\mathrm{\,primes}} (p^{-z})^m$, we have $z$ in the exponent in $(R)$
, but polynomial in $(I)$.

Why is that?

EDIT: Further I found the following on [The Riemann hypothesis for ($q+1$-regular) graphs](https://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/2014/08/18/the-riemann-hypothesis-for-graphs/):
$$\displaystyle \zeta(s) = \prod_{p \ \rm prime} \frac { 1 } { 1 - p^{-s}} \ \ \ \ \ (2),
$$
compared to 
$$
\displaystyle z(s) = \prod_{p \ \rm prime\ cycle} \frac 1 { 1 - (\color{red}{q^{|p|}})^{-s }} \ \ \ \ \ (5)
$$
which still looks confusing to me since we build a product over primes in Riemann's case, where the prime $p$ varies, while a product over a fixed  variable $\color{red}q$ with the length of the prime cycle as an exponent in Ihara's case, but since $(5)$ would just use powers of $q$, like as I would restrict my set of primes to only one single prime in $(2)$ it might be OK...

Comment: Why do you think they ought to be the same?

Comment: @GregMartin I don't think so. It just confuses me. A reason why they are different could be that Riemann deals with an infinite sum and Ihara, as far as I got it, with a finite graph. Could it be something like that?

Comment: Why is it okay that $x^5$ and $5^x$ are different? Because there's no reason to think they should be the same.

Comment: @GregMartin is it because Ihara's zeta is based on the additive operation of symmetric differences of elementary cycles while Riemann is based on the multiplicative group of prime numbers?

Comment: Yes this is additive vs multiplicative norms. For a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ in one case the norm has the form $|\mathfrak{p}| = a^{deg(p)}$ in the other it is $|\mathfrak{p}| = a^{\ln p}$. The zeta function is a function of $a = e^{-s}$. In both case we are looking at multiplicative monoids (instead of graphs you should look at the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ where $deg(f)$ is the degree of a polynomial). The functional equation appears when the multiplicative monoid is inside a commutative ring with an acceptable Fourier theory (Poisson summation formula)

Comment: @user1952009 where does the norm come in in both cases? Is it the norm in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$? Did you mean "$deg(p)$ is the degree of the polynomial"?

Comment: I meant if $M$ is a free multiplicative monoid and we have a multiplicative function $h : M \to \mathbb{R}$ then $\zeta_M(s) = \sum_{x \in M} |h(x)|^{-s} = \prod_{p \in M} \frac{1}{1-h(p)^{-s}}$ where $p$ are the generators. For $M = \mathbb{Z}^*$ the natural choice is $h(n) = n$, for $M = \mathbb{F}_p[x]^*$ the natural choice is $h(f) = e^{deg(f)}$. In one case $h(n)$ is an integer, in the other case it is $\log h(f)$ that is an integer.

Comment: If $M$ is inside a ring $R$ with an acceptable Fourier theory then there is a natural choice for $h$ (such that $\zeta_M$ has a functional equation), this is the [local fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field) vs global fields theory. Both have a Riemann hypothesis, but the RH is non-trivial (involving prime numbers) only for global fields. For local fields, the $\zeta$ function is rational.